# Should lshw list my USB hub with a USB capability of 3.00 instead of 2.0?

Tags: 20.04, usb, dell

Had a powered USB hub plugged into the laptop since September, and no problems until I did a physical move of the laptop and a second reboot. The error:

```
Nov  2 02:59:34 linux kernel: [166196.002037] usb usb3-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
```

Error occurs 4 - 8 times a minute. The application that depends on the external drives connected to the hub is still operational but it's error rate increased after the usb port errors started happening.  I guess I'll start with this question: should the lshw display below of the usbhost show a usb capability of 3.00 instead of 2.0?  Do I need to install a newer driver?

The hub is plugged into a 3.0 slot (with the ss indicator). Laptop is a Dell Inspiron 14R. Linux Ubuntu 20.04 (command-line only, no gui).  All cables between hub and laptop port are firmly connected. All led lights on.

```
 *-usbhost:0
            product: xHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 5.4.0-131-generic xhci-hcd
            physical id: 0
            bus info: usb@2
            logical name: usb2
            version: 5.04
            capabilities: usb-2.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=9 speed=480Mbit/s
          *-usb:0
               description: USB hub
               vendor: Hitachi, Ltd
               physical id: 2
               bus info: usb@2:2
               version: 1.00
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
             *-usb:0 UNCLAIMED
                  description: Human interface device
                  product: Nano S
                  vendor: Ledger
                  physical id: 1
                  bus info: usb@2:2.1
                  version: 2.01
                  serial: 0001
                  capabilities: usb-2.00
                  configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
             *-usb:1
                  description: Mass storage device
                  product: PNY ELITE PSSD
                  vendor: PNY
                  physical id: 2
                  bus info: usb@2:2.2
                  version: 1.00
                  serial: 511220215208AB470004
                  capabilities: usb-2.10 scsi
                  configuration: driver=uas maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```